# What is the spectrum of this matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$A_n=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 2 & \cdots & 2 & 2\\
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & 3 & 3\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-1 & n-1\\
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-1 & n
\end{bmatrix}.$$

What are the eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenvectors of $A_n$?

Comment: Coefficients of the characteristic polynomial for $A_n$ can be found here http://oeis.org/A202672

Comment: it looks like the spectrums of these matrices have the interlacing property; the eigenvalues of $A_n$ separate that of $A_{n+1}.$ i suspect there is three term recurrence relations satisfied by the characteristic polynomials. reminds me of the tridiagonal matrices.

Comment: Here it is immediate that the determinant of the matrix is 1. It is invertible therefore.

Comment: @abel  Yes, it surely can be converted into a tridiagonal or upper triangular system of linear equations while solving for eigenvector. But still I am not getting the eigenvectors as well as the eigenvalues.

Comment: $$A_n^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 2 & -1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 2 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 2 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$ 
Therefore finding the eigenvalues of the above tridiagonal matrix must work as the eigenvalues $A_n$ would be just its reciprocal and the eigenvectors remain the same.

Comment: @G_0_pi_i_e The eigenpairs of $A_n^{-1}$ are the eigenpairs of the difference boundary value problem
$$
u_0 = 0\\
-u_{k+1} +2u_k -u_{k-1} = \lambda u_k, \quad k = 1, \dots, n-1\\
u_{n} - u_{n-1} = \lambda u_n
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the inverse of $A_n$ is 
$$
A^{-1}_n = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 2 & -1 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 2 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 2 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Solving $A_n^{-1} x = \lambda^{-1} x$ is the same that solving difference problem
$$\begin{aligned}
x_0 &= 0\\
-x_{k+1} + 2x_k -x_{k-1} &= \lambda^{-1} x_k, \quad k = 1, \dots, n-1\\
x_n - x_{n-1} &= \lambda^{-1} x_n
\end{aligned}
$$
Substituting $x_k = \sin \omega k$ gives following system of equations for $\omega, \lambda$
$$
4\sin^2\frac{\omega}{2} = \lambda^{-1}\\
(1-\lambda^{-1})\sin \omega n = \sin \omega (n-1)
$$
or
$$
1 - 4\sin^2\frac{\omega}{2} = \frac{\sin \omega(n-1)}{\sin \omega n}
$$
That equation has exactly $n$ different solutions for $\omega$ in $(0, \pi)$ since left is monotonically decreasing and right is increasing and has $n-1$ poles (see image for $n=5$). Values outside of $(0, \pi)$ produce the same values for $\lambda$ due to periodicity. So
$$
\lambda_j^{-1} = 4\sin^2\frac{\omega_j}{2}\\
(x_j)_k = \sin k \omega_j
$$

[image]

Comment: thank you for your valuable comment. But again I have the problem. Because $\omega_j$ here comes from the solution of the equation $1-4\sin^2\frac{\omega}{2}=\frac{\sin\omega (n-1)}{\sin\omega n}$. I need explicit solution only. So could we have expression for $\omega_j$?